# Which repository access method is used to create a new “working copy”, file:/// or svn:// in same machine?

Tags: svn

I have setup svnserve server (1.6.5,plain, without apache) on Fedora. 
The users, who has accounts in same machine want to checkout a working copy. I have
read svnbook and other sites and found file:/// access method is being used to checkout as

svn checkout file:///var/svn/repos/myproject/trunk myproject ( ref:svnbook)

I am little confused! As svnbook also says "Clients contact an svnserve server by using 
URLs that begin with the svn://" 
So, my question is, which method user will use to create their working copy?

Thankyou.
Banani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The svn:// scheme goes to a socket. If you want to checkout directly from the filesystem, use the file:// scheme (you don't use the server in that case).

(You could use file://, svn://, svn+ssh://, http:// or https:// to check out a working dir on the same machine, but except for file:// those all require running some kind of server.)

Answer (score 1):

If the users have file system access to the repository, they *can* use file://.  However, **this is probably a bad idea**.

The recommended practice for a multi-user environment is to set up svnserve and access the repository via the svn:// protocol (or http:// or https:// as the case may be).

From the [Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) section of the svnbook

> Do not be seduced by the simple idea
>   of having all of your users access a
>   repository directly via file:// URLs.
>   Even if the repository is readily
>   available to everyone via a network
>   share, this is a bad idea. It removes
>   any layers of protection between the
>   users and the repository: users can
>   accidentally (or intentionally)
>   corrupt the repository database, it
>   becomes hard to take the repository
>   offline for inspection or upgrade, and
>   it can lead to a mess of file
>   permission problems (see the section
>   called “Supporting Multiple Repository
>   Access Methods”).